# document.querySelector null in js

Tags: javascript, function

i have this code>>

```js
function myFunction() {
var a = document.querySelector('input[name="qa1"]:checked').value;
var b = document.querySelector('input[name="qa2"]:checked').value;
var sum = a + b;
alert(sum)
}
```

```html
<label><input name="q1" value="5" required="" type="radio"> answare</label>
<label><input name="q2" value="10" required="" type="radio"> answare2</label>

<input class="submit-button" value="Score my Answers" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
```

i want get alert with sum of q1 and q2 when click Score my Answers button and thay are checked
please help

Comment: The "name" values in your HTML and your JavaScript do not match.

Comment: `[name="qa1"]:` does not match `<input name="q1" `

Comment: Also need to consider your selectors won't find anything if that element isn't  checked

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in name. Secondly the value is a string so the output will be `510` because of string concatenation. Use `parseInt` to convert string to num before doing addition

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked').value;
  var b = document.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked').value;
  var sum = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
  alert(sum)
}
```

```html
<label><input name="q1" value="5" required="" type="radio"> answare</label>
<label><input name="q2" value="10" required="" type="radio"> answare2</label>

<input class="submit-button" value="Score my Answers" name="submit" type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
```